# Exercise $0.11$ from Leinster's Basic Category Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, universal-property

This is Exercise $0.11$ from Leinster's [*Basic Category Theory*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09375).

> Let $\theta:G \to H$ be a group homomorphism. Associated with $\theta$ is a diagram $$\ker(\theta) \stackrel{\iota}{\hookrightarrow} G \substack{\stackrel{\theta}{\longrightarrow}\\[-1em] \underset{\varepsilon}{\longrightarrow}} H$$ where $\iota$ is the inclusion and $\varepsilon$ is the trivial map. Find the a universal property satisfied by the pair $(\ker(\theta), \iota)$ of the given diagram.

I'm still very new to the universal properties so I don't really understand the question. Are they asking me to find a commutative diagram considering $G, H$ and $\ker(\theta)$ along with $\iota$?

Comment: Replace the kernel with $A$ and $\iota$ with another map $j$. So now you have the pair $(A,j)$ that goes into the diagram at the same spot. What kind of relationship do you get between $A$ and the kernel?

Comment: Which book is this? I think it might be asking a bit much of the reader, who might still be uncomfortable with universal properties... I'm about to teach a class, but I can answer in an hour or so if nobody's helped yet ^_^

Comment: it is apparently [Leinster's Basic Category Theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375). Always, always use the author and title. Especially with a book title as commonplace as "Basic <subjectarea>"

Comment: A hint that does not spoil the fun: you have to define a category where, among all pairs of the same type, $(\ker\theta,\iota)$ is a terminal object. This will be called a category of "cones" for the pair of parallel maps... and certainly all these names are present in Leinster book!

Comment: They are, but they seem to become after the chapter which this question regards. I feel like I should be able to do this without any fancy knowledge of category theory yet. @fosco

Comment: Do you know the universal property of pullbacks (aka fiber products) or equalizers yet? The kernel is a special case of both of these. If you read Example 0.8, the author basically tells you the universal property. The universal property can be stated using a commutative diagram. It should be something like, "For any ___ such that ____, there is a unique ___ such that ___", where the last ___ could be "the following diagram commutes".

Answer (score 0):

A universal property is roughly an essential solution to some universal problem. This might not be of much help so let me expand using your example of kernels.

Consider the following: We are given a group homomorphism $\theta\colon G\to H$ and are asking ourselves which group is *perfectly* annihilated by $\theta$. The obvious group-theoretic answer is the kernel $\ker\theta\le G$ which is a (normal) subgroup of $G$. It is perfect in the sense that **any** subset which is annihilated by $\theta$ is necessarily contained in the kernel.

Universal properties aim at generalizing such rough intutitons in the right way (the right way being category-theoretic in this case). For this we have to replace any set-theoretic considerations -such as containment- by appropriate arrow-theoretic concepts which often boil down to certain factorization properties.

Suppose that $\zeta\colon K\to G$ is such that $\theta\zeta=0$, i.e. any element of $K$ is annihilated along the composition of $\zeta$ and $\theta$. Then we want that this map factors along the canonical inclusion $\ker\theta\to G$ meaning that the elements of $K$ may be realized as elements of $\ker\theta$. In fact, we have a bit more freedom in our definiton of a category-theoretic kernel (although we can recover the usual notion immediately).

Hence a universal property is usually a combination of some object (=group) and morphism(s) (=group homomorphism(s)) expressing certain factorization properties. In the given case we consider an specialization of a so-called equalizer diagram. What you want to find are the appropriate universal diagrams the pair $(\ker\theta,\iota)$ satisfies (**HINT:** What characterizes the kernel subgroup among all subgroups?).